# showing a distinct list of specific atoms in a list in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, boolean-expression

I am modeling boolean expressions as lisp lists like this : *'(NOT (AND 0 (OR B C)))*
I need to write a function that displays  the **variables** in the expression
the variabels are everything except for digits  , AND , OR.
any body can help me ?
example : the output of the previous expression is : *(B C)*

Here's my attempt:

```
(defun print-vars (L1) 
  "Append L1 by L2." 
  (if (= 0 (list-length (L1)))
      nil 
      (if (= 1 (list-length (L1))) 
          L1 
          (cons (print-vars (remove-duplicates (first (L1)))) 
                (print-vars (remove-duplicates (rest (L1))))))))
```

Comment: Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Comment: i tried so much using remove-duplicates and recursion but it didn't work , so i guess my work is an embarrassment :(

Comment: The point of SO is helping when code doesn't work. Posting non-working code is therefore normal and shows you have tried. Rainer is right, post your attempt. Additionally this will give us a lot of clues so that we can help you better,

Comment: okay i will do it later , thanks for the clarification ..

Comment: here is my old try :

(defun print-vars (L1)
  "Append L1 by L2."
  if(= 0 (list-length  (L1))
      nil
 if(= 1 (list-length  (L1))
   L1
    (cons (print-vars (remove-duplicates (first (L1)))) (print-vars (remove-duplicates (rest (L1)))) ))))

but i guess its so dump..

Comment: You should not lie in your docstrings.

Comment: damn it i forgot to remove this comment , i was editing another function :/
i wish i can remove the docstring..and replace with "Search for variables in L1"

Comment: can anyone edit my attempt and remove the wrong docstring so it wont confuse readers , and replace it with "Search for variables in L1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(defun vars (exp &optional (res nil))
  (if exp
      (if (consp exp)
          (vars (cdr exp) (vars (car exp) res))
          (if (or (numberp exp) (member exp '(and or not))) 
              res
              (adjoin exp res)))
      res))
```

then

```
? (vars '(NOT (AND 0 (OR B C)))) 
(C B)
? (vars '(NOT (AND C (OR B C))))
(B C)
```

Comment: it seems that you are so skilled in lisp  , i need to ask you  a question  , how can i reach you ?

Comment: Just ask your question here on SO. Many people are here who can help,